# Remove Item from Minicart throws Invalid Form Key error in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, addtocart, controllers, error-log

I had installed a fresh setup of Magento ver 1.9.3.9 and when I add the product to cart and click on Remove Item from Minicart it gives me exception error and page goes to `There has been an error processing your request`

When I checked my var/reports it shows this error:

> "Invalid form key";i:1;s:1012:"#0 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(641): Mage::throwException('Invalid form ke...')

I had again download the fresh zip of Magento 1.9.3.9 and again integrated the app/code/Mage/Checkout module by disabling previous one. But still it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can  increasing the following PHP settings (`php.ini`) for doing imports:

**Error cause:**

```
post_max_size = 128M
```

as suggested in some articles about import...

After setting them back to default (64M)

**Solution:**

```
post_max_size = 64M
```

and ,naturally, deleting all the cache folders under `/var/cache/`, everything went back to normal.